# Template function: perform conversion based on typename

Tags: c++, oop, templates

Is there a way to achieve something like this in C++:

```
template<typename T>
T function()
{
    std::string result = getRes();
    // if (type == string)
        return result;
    // else if (type == numeric)
        return std::stoul(result, nullptr);
}
```

Assuming the result variable type is always known (in this case string). The return type is defined by the template in the function call, e.g.:

```
int x = function<int>();
```

I know that there are things like `std::is_integral` or `std::is_same`. With those functions I could determine the type of T. However it does not seem to work, because it cannot be evaluated during compile time and therefore the compiler throws errors.

Comment: You can use a `stringstream`.

Comment: You could use `if constexpr (blah) {blah}`, but the stringstream is probably better.

Comment: The stringstream solution seems to work, thank you. Do you want to write an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
T function()
{
    std::string result = getRes();
    stringstream ss;
    ss << result;
    T value;
    ss >> value;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Check if this works for a string `result` that contains spaces. string extraction stops at whitespace,

Answer (score 1):

You can use SFINAE to distinguish between two versions of a function template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

std::string getRes() { return "1729"; }

template < typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T,std::string>::value, void** >::type = nullptr >
std::string function()
{
    return getRes();
}

template < typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void** >::type = nullptr >
unsigned long function()
{

    return std::stoul(getRes());
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long ul = function<unsigned long>();
    std::string s = function<std::string>();

    std::cout << ul << ' ' << s << '\n';
}
```

---

A bit shorter in C++14 with `auto` return type and `enable_if_t`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

std::string getRes() { return "1729"; }

template < typename T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T,std::string>::value, void** > = nullptr >
auto function()
{
    return getRes();
}

template < typename T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void** > = nullptr >
auto function()
{

    return std::stoul(getRes());
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long ul = function<unsigned long>();
    std::string s = function<std::string>();

    std::cout << ul << ' ' << s << '\n';
}
```